# Is there a decent command Reference for VBA and Access 97?

Tags: ms-access, vba, documentation, reference

I've spent the last weeks looking at some codes @ microsoft's website just to realize that I was looking @ VB.NET code instead of VBA.

Not that I know the diference between them.

But a good ref. library and documentation would help a lot, something similar to the javadocs.

I've been working with some export functions latetly and I can't find the full command list inside the software.

Any hints? Tips?
I'm not a total n00b at the subject and I'm just looking for a good place to start learning more than the basics. 
But I don't wanna spend another week looking for a command to delete a file or to reorganize a CVS.

Comment: Why VBA and Access 97? Why use deprecated versions and not use the newer versions? Do you have a very rigid and specific system you are working with?

Comment: Yeah, I have a really rigid and specific system that will only allow me to use VBA and JAVA. AND the only version of Access I may use is the 97 distribuition. I already spend a lot of time learning how to use VBA with our main software (Personal Communications) but I have no idea how to use VBA by itself, so I'm having a lot of trouble exporting tables and moving some files around the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [Access 2003 VBA reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa296748%28v=office.11%29.aspx). It should be the same for most questions.

Also, there are an incredible number of discussions on other, less-distinguished forums about nearly anything you could want to do in VBA. I've never had trouble finding the answer to specific questions.

Comment: no. 
There is a TON of VB Code that is not available with VBA for MS97

Comment: Better go to a library, then. There seem to be plenty of book references.

Comment: http://www.worldcat.org/search?qt=worldcat_org_all&q=access+97+vba

Comment: I cannot believe that my local library had more information than the web. Thanks Patrick.

Comment: Really? I'm glad that worked. I guess people in 1997 weren't yet in the habit of uploading their knowledge to the internet...

Answer (score 0):

There's actually an in-editor API reference using the built-in help.  I found it pretty useful back when I was doing VBA.  MS has an article about some of the caveats [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163435) (mainly, you had to do a full install)

Comment: The built-in help is in portuguese. I have no problem reading it, but I do have a problem using commands such as Abrir instead of Open. And Microsoft's articles are really confusing and most of the time they don't apply to the version I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Years earlier it seems that this was an easier question to answer. However here a few links I found relevant to  your question. These are fairly easy to find using [Google](http://google.com) with a query of "Visual Basic 6.0". Please note most of these are for Visual Basic 6.0 which is similar to Visual Basic 5 and of course VBA.

- [Large Collection of VB6 samples/documentation](http://www.vb6.us/)
- [Visual Basic 6 - 'Cheat Sheet'](http://www.dreamincode.net/downloads/ref_sheets/vb_reference_sheet.pdf)
- [VBA Examples - Including Access '97](http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/index.htm)
- [Sample VB6 code from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ee410535)